# ShareLinkContent has small image

Tags: android, facebook

I'm getting a problem about ShareLinkContent. .
I shared this pic below through my App. I have a problem about the size of the image

main image

[image]

I shared that pic through my App, then the shared post display like this
[image]

but I want a display post like this
[image]

based on what? so can I get result like him. why do I get such small image result in sharing?

```
  ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                                .setImageUrl(Uri.parse(post_image_url))
                                .setContentTitle(party.getTitle() + " - " + Utility.convertDBDateForPartyDisplayFormat(party.getDate_time_start()))
                                .setContentDescription(post.getMessage() + " - " + post.getNick_name() + " \n@ " + party.getStore_name())
                                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(URLManager.FACEBOOK_APP_LINK + "?type=past_party&id=" + party_id))
                                .build();
                        shareDialog.show(linkContent);
```

Comment: Posting aws urls in SO is not secure.You better upload here directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the Image Sizes best practices by facebook
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices
based on the image size you set to the setImageUrl() it changes.If you want image  larger in the share you need to send the larger image as shown in the above link.

Comment: Thanks. It really helps me. now I'll just have to test it